# Using a MySQL query with variables from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

In MySQL Workbench the MySQL query

```sql
SET @rownum=-1;
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS row_num
FROM someTable
```

returns a table where the value of row_num starts at 0 and goes up by 1 for each row:

```
+---------+
| row_num |
+---------+
| 0       |
+---------+
| 1       |
+---------+
| 2       |

  ....
```

I am trying to execute the same query from C#.

```cs
string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" +
    "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" + "ALLOW USER VARIABLES = true;";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand command;
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

connection.Open();
command = connection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_num FROM someTable";
command.Parameters.Add("@rownum", MySqlDbType.Int32);
command.Parameters["@rownum"].Value = -1;
adapter.SelectCommand = command;

DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
```

The last line of the above results in the following MySqlException

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':= -1 + 1 AS row_num FROM someTable'

Why does the query not work from C#?

Comment: why `:` after `@rownum` ?

Comment: You dont declare @rownum like in the original query

Comment: @Ehsan: becasue := is the assignment operator in MySQL. Using `@rownum = @rownun + 1` in the MySQL query results in the comparison -1 = (-1 + 1) and so each row has the value 0 for row_num

Comment: @Mihai: isn't `@rownum declared indirectly via command.Parameters?

Comment: @Mihai: and you can see that MySQL recognizes `@rownum` as a variable because the error message shows -1 after the :=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines for parameters:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@rownum", MySqlDbType.Int32);
command.Parameters["@rownum"].Value = -1;
```

And use this query:

```
command.CommandText = "SET @rownum=-1;SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS row_num FROM someTable";
```

The way your are doing is both "@rownum" will be replaced with -1. So you end up with a query like this:

```
SELECT -1:= -1 + 1 AS row_num FROM someTable
```

Comment: Execution of the query and any variable assignment takes place in the MySQL engine. Your string.Format results in exactly the same CommandText as my code uses and results in the same error too

Comment: Are you sure? I quickly had made an edit to my post. Please make sure you are using the latest edit because yes, the first one was incorrect but I made the edit so fast. You must have picked it up before I edited my answer.

Comment: I have tried both (before the edit and after). Both result in the same error

Comment: Another approach. Please try that.

Comment: The connection string is wrong.  Paddy should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this solution only works if specify the parameter "AllowUserVariables=True"  in the connectionstring

Comment: Please add this type of answer in the comment box

Comment: I disagree with Pratik, this should be the accepted answer. This is the reason it didn't work in the first place, from the original question, and it helped me.  If you look at his 'Connection-String' he has "Allow User Variables" incorrectly.