# unable to use mysql assigning operator in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to use assigning operator `@a := 0` for crossjoin (mysql) in my c# program. But it throws error saying

> Fatal error encountered during command execution. Parameter '@a' must be defined.

the below query executes well in my mysql tool. but fails to perform while using it in my C# programming.

```
string str = "select t1.x1,(@a := @a + t1.x1) x2 from table1 t1 cross join (select @a := 0) params";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, connection);
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Output should be:

x1       x2

1        1

2        3

3        6

4        10

5        15

How do i solve this?
or is there a work around for this?

Comment: What's the C# code you're using to execute the query? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245789/is-it-possible-to-use-mysql-assignment-operator-in-a-mysqlcommand) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212179/using-a-mysql-query-with-variables-from-c-sharp) suggest removing any parameters set in C# for the variable in question.

Comment: @Diado, I have edited my question with the code sample

Comment: The query code is legal for MySQL (except the `ORDER BY` clause needed for deterministic result). So this is c# issue (and the error message is c# too). Try `string str = "SET @a := 0; select x1,(@a := @a + x1) x2 from table1;";`

Comment: Specify MySQL version. Maybe UDV use is excess?

Comment: @Akina, i tried it and still same error.

Comment: Try: string str = "select t1.x1,(\@a := \@a + t1.x1) x2 from table1 t1 cross join (select \@a := 0) params"; and use cmd.ExecuteReader(); instead cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @FranCerezo, no luck. that too is not working in c#.

Comment: .NET thinks @a is a not declared SqlParameter, if you can not escape @ character, you are going to get desired result set by other way, maybe linq. Or you can create a stored procedure and call it. This way you avoid the problem with @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, MySQL Connector/NET does not allow variables in SQL statements, only command parameters. If you use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) you will get a more helpful error message:

> Parameter '@a' must be defined. To use this as a variable, set 'Allow User Variables=true' in the connection string.

As this states, add `AllowUserVariables=true` to your connection string to permit the use of variables in SQL commands.